# Get the last two events of a id and arrange it

Tags: r, data-analysis

This is just a sample dataframe.

[image]

I want to obtain the last two Events of each `id_num` and make another data frame consisting of the `id_num` and last two Events as `Event1` and `Event2` respectively.

[image]

How can it be done?

Comment: Instead of sharing images try to share `dput` of your example so that it is easy for others to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in one line using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id_num = rep(1:3, 4), event = paste0("E", 1:12))
    #     id_num event
    #  1:      1    E1
    #  2:      2    E2
    #  3:      3    E3
    #  4:      1    E4
    #  5:      2    E5
    #  6:      3    E6
    #  7:      1    E7
    #  8:      2    E8
    #  9:      3    E9
    # 10:      1   E10
    # 11:      2   E11
    # 12:      3   E12

dt[, .(event_1 = .SD[(.N-1), event], event_2 = .SD[.N, event]), by = id_num] 
    #    id_num event_1 event_2
    # 1:      1      E7     E10
    # 2:      2      E8     E11
    # 3:      3      E9     E12
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea using `tidyverse` package (with @Florian's data set),

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(id_num) %>% 
 mutate(cnt = seq(n())) %>% 
 slice((last(cnt)-1):last(cnt)) %>% 
 spread(cnt, event)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   id_num [2]
#  id_num    `2`    `3`
#*  <dbl> <fctr> <fctr>
#1      1     E2     E3
#2      2     E4     E5
```

Comment: Oops, my answer was incorrect indeed. Here is the dataset for your answer: `df = data.frame(id_num=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),event=c("E1","E2","E3","E3","E4","E5"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base R with `aggregate` and `tail`.

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(event~id_num, data=df, tail, 2))
  id_num event.1 event.2
1      1      E2      E3
2      2      E4      E5
```

You need to also use `do.call` `data.frame` to the result because the data structure of the output of `aggregate` is two column data.frame where the second column is made up of matrices. After the `do.call`, we get the desired structure of a three column data.frame.